# display select options based on value exists in database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<%= form_for(@timetable) do |f| %>     
<% Timetable.all.each do |t| %>
      <% if t.day == "Monday" %>
        <%= f.select :day, options_for_select(%w[Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday]) %>
      <% elsif t.day == "Tuesday" %>
        <%= f.select :day, options_for_select(%w[Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday]) %>
      <% elsif t.day == "Wednesday" %>
        <%= f.select :day, options_for_select(%w[Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday]) %>
      <% elsif t.day == "Thursday" %>
        <%= f.select :day, options_for_select(%w[Friday Saturday Sunday]) %>
      <% elsif t.day == "Friday" %>
        <%= f.select :day, options_for_select(%w[Saturday Sunday]) %>
      <% elsif t.day == "Saturday" %>
        <%= f.select :day, options_for_select(%w[Sunday]) %>
      <% else %>
        <%= f.select :day, options_for_select(%w[Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday]) %>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

If the value "Monday" exits in the database field "day" then the value  "Monday" should not appear in the select options. Is there any other efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is this code not working or you are looking for a refactoring ?

Comment: code not working as well as a approach for other efficient way

Comment: what is `@timetable`?

Comment: <%= form_for(@timetable) do |f| %> 
 //code goes here
<% end %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% values = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"] %>
<%# Timetable.all.each do |t| %>
        <%= f.select :day, options_for_select(values - [@timetable.day], selected: @timetable.day ) %>
<%# end %>
```

I comment out the looping as there are showing multiple select box.

Comment: getting error. undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Actually you are getting this error becoz somehow  your 'values' variable is nil

Comment: @rinold, have you insert the `values` variable in to `<%%>` sign? I missed that part.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% Timetable.all.each do |t| %>
  <%= f.select :day, options_for_select(%w[Sunday Saturday Friday Thursday Wednesday Tuesday Monday].take_while { |day| day != t.day }.reverse!, selected: @timetable.day ) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: select box should appear only once

Comment: > select box should appear only once

That is not what your example showed ;)